# Count with multipal criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Hi guys,

I'm looking for a solution in order to count the number of rows in a table (my table contains 2 columns which are AE and AF) which well reply my crriterias (for example "Zone 1" and "Couche 1" at the same time).

I have tried the sumproduct and countif but it returns 0.
On the other hand, I've used simply if fuction but it seems like excel doesnt understand.
For more details, I attached two photos (sorry that all fuction are written in French...)
Thanks a lot if you guys have an idea to solve it!!!

Comment: Try `COUNTIFS()` instead of `COUNTIF()`.

Answer (score 0):

`=COUNTIFS(AE:AE, "Zone 1", AF:AF, "Couche 1")`

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, the values in thoses 2 columns weren't entered by keyboard but they are results of a logical test (If function) that (propably) make Excel don't understand the function (with your solution, excel always returns 0).... I can't even compare them with a specific text.

Comment: It should not matter. What does `=if(AE="Zone 7","A","B")` return?

Comment: I've tried for 2 cases (one with typed value and other with result from a logical fuction) for exactly same value but excel returned differently!! It was "A" for the first case and "B" for the second. Still don't understand why....However, by replacing the term "Zone 1" by a number it worked normally